# Remove Subcategories title and links from bottom of Category blog

Tags: joomla-3.x, category-blog, subcategories

I am using a category blog menu item type in order to display article intro’s for a number of subcategories. Under the blog layout settings, 'include subcategories' is therefore set to all in order that all of the child subcategories appear within the category blog.

It all looks fine except at the bottom of the page the title ‘Subcategories’ appears along with links to the subcategories.  This is unnecessary and pointless as they are already listed above as article intro’s.  I would like to remove this but can't figure out how to do it?

[image]

Many thanks in advance for your time.

Emma

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Exchange.

This is controlled in the menu item.  You need to:

1. Go into your administration section of Joomla!
2. Click on Menus
3. Go to the menu that you are using e.g. "main menu"
4. Select the menu item e.g. "day trips"
5. Click on the tab called "category"
6. You can choose the dropdown I show in my image "subcategory levels", set this to "none" and your subcategories will stop showing

[image: how-to-turn-off-subcategory-images]

Comment: THANK YOU!!  This was exactly what I needed, it worked perfectly.  I really appreciate you taking the time to respond.

Comment: No problems, if you found my answer useful, please mark it as correct so others can benefit.